# Calling jquery function with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, global

[image]

I'm trying to call fxn function outside $(document).ready(), but I can't get it working. It returns ReferenceError: fxn is not defined.. anything I missed?

Comment: you should call in `document.ready()`... otherwise `function call` line will be executed before `function definition` or every thing outside of `document.ready()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way jQuery works.  This error is predictable.

What is happening, is the declaration of `fxn` is waiting until the document is actually ready.  Where the call to this method is not.  So, by attempting this you are in essence trying to call a function that doesn't yet exist.

As per:  http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
>   jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside
>   `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included
>   inside `$( window ).load(function() { ... })` will run once the entire
>   page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.